# implement 2 cancel button in a segue

Tags: ios

I have a view controller with 2 different segues that goes to 2 different view controller,and i have to implement the cancel button in both the controllers.When i press the cancel button,in both the controller,the view will return to the initial view controller.My question is how can i implement the buttons?When i try with this code the compiler warning:Multiple declaration of method "cancel:" found and ignored.Thank you.

interface:

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;    
-(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;    
-(IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

implementation:

```
-(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue    
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]){            
        AddSightingViewController *addController = [segue sourceViewController];            
        if (addController.birdSighting) {

            [self.dataController
             addBirdSightingWithSighting:addController.birdSighting];

            [[self tableView]reloadData];                
        }            
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}


-(IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue    
{        
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput"]){            
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to preform extra actions when the cancel button is clicked (like resetting variables or calling other methods), or are you just looking to change screens?  If you do need to change something extra, do you need to change it on the initial view, or on one of the other two controllers?  Looking at just the code you posted, I would guess that you're only looking to change screens, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do. But I think the cancel method needs to be in the 2 child View Controllers, not in the main one. One for each controller (and one cancel button for each view). That way you won't have any problems with multiple declarations of a method.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I conclude that you are using (or want use) exit segues for canceling.

First, you should only have one method declaration and implementation for your cancel method in the initial view controller. In your storyboard create exit segues by control-dragging from your cancel buttons to the green exit icon blow the view controller and select the cancel method defined in the initial view controller. Do that for both view controllers. You should also give your exit segues different identifiers in your storyboard (you need to select the segue in the Document Outline to change its identifier).

Then your cancel method in your initial view controller can look something like this:

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue    
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput1"]) {
        // Do something
    } else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput2"]) {
        // Do something different
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do anything when canceling just leave the method empty.

Comment: Do you mean for this to be in the Initial view controller or one of the 2 other view controllers?

Comment: The cancel method is in the initial view controller since it is an exist segue.

Comment: No ,i don't need to perform extra action when the cancel button is clicked.your method work right,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to go back you need to implement an unwind segue.

To do this, define a method to go back on the original view controller (the one you want to go back). You can leave the method empty.

```
- (IBAction)methodName:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
}
```

Then on IB ctrl + drag from the button (or from the view controller) to the green "exit" icon. Select the methodName from the popup menu. If you did it from the view controller set the identifier on the segue and call it with performSegueWithIdentifier: from the button action.

Considerations:

- The method name will be detected in every view controller on the storyboard.
- You can define the same method name in different view controllers, but when you execute the unwind segue, you will go back to the most recent on the navigation path.